# How to show null fields with mysql query when no value available?

Tags: mysql

I've two table "Users" and "Recipient" . Now I want to show all offices and total recipient on this office. But My query returns which offices have count number. But I need to show all office and count numbers.

like :

```
id          office_name           count
========================================
1             Dhaka                0
2             Chittagong           2
```

current query: "

```
SELECT users.id as office_id, users.office_name , count(recipient.id) as total_count 
FROM users 
right outer JOIN recipient on recipient.office_id = users.id
WHERE ( users.del_status = 0 and users.type='agency')
order by users.id
```

"

Users Table:
[image]

Recipient Table: 
[image]

Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `recipient` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `reg_no` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `disability_type` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `education` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `office_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `del_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;      

 CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `office_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `district_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upazilla_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `del_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Do you have master list of offices in a separate table?

Comment: Hi Mehta, here is the dump: recipient: https://file.town/download/43pd2m218rxc7hd6cxb76g11y    
users:  https://file.town/download/y3uiepe5z4b9gegff9aracaoj

Comment: Can you share the structure of office table as well?

Comment: Hi Mehta, I updated question. You'll find structure there

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to get all the offices even if they don't have entries in `recipient` table, e.g.:

```
SELECT u.id, u.office_name, COUNT(r.id) AS `count`
FROM users u LEFT JOIN recipient r ON u.id = r.office_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.office_name;
```

Comment: Mehta, can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791207/mysql-query-get-dynamic-column-and-its-value